# Github local repo with VS code : Too many changes

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have install Github Enterprise on a self-managed server. I am connecting to my Github repo through VS Code. Every time I open VS code:

1 - It's trying to connect automatically to my cloud repo (Which I would like to be able to manually connect)
2 - VS code is installed in Anaconda and it's detecting 5000 changes....all anaconda files on my local machine

Can anyone help me with this issue?
thank you

Comment: Hi David... welcome to SO. You're asking 2 questions and suggest you break them up. But briefly... with Source Control setup for your project VSCode is going to use that Source Control I'm not sure if that something you can disable, I doubt it.

I think your second question is about how to setup an Anaconda project for source control. In particular, what is the proper .gitignore file for an Anaconda project. the .gitignore file tells GIT to ignore certain files so they are not included in what you checkin to source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have Anaconda or a conda environment installed into your project folder? Then you have to add that folder to your .gitignore file.

In VSCode you can rightclick on one of the 5000 files, select "Add to .gitignore" from the context menu, then the file .gitignore opens and you can delete everything but the top folder from the new entry and then that folder will be ignored.

Btw., VSCode doesn't update your local git repository automatically but just checks, if there are new changes in your remote repo (github) or how far it is behind your local changes. You can see that in the VSCode status bar. If you want to actually change one of the repos you either have to "pull" or "push" manually.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I really appreciate it. It's just a lot of new software and concepts to take in at the same time.